# webticker doesn't work after .toggle()

Tags: jquery, toggle, ticker

jQuery webticker is working fine as long as its state not toggled. You can run the below snippet and see that it is working fine. But once you click on the button to hide it and then click it to show it again, it stops working. I can't initialize the webticker every time I toggled it.

```js
/*!
 * webTicker 2.1.1
 * Examples and documentation at:
 * http://jonmifsud.com/open-source/jquery/jquery-webticker/
 * 2011 Jonathan Mifsud
 * Version: 2.1.1 (23-MAY-2013)
 * Dual licensed under the Creative Commons and DonationWare licenses:
 * http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/
 * https://github.com/jonmifsud/Web-Ticker/blob/master/licence.md
 * Requires:
 * jQuery v1.4.2 or later
 *
 */
(function($) {

  var cssTransitionsSupported = (function() {
    var s = document.createElement('p').style,
      v = ['ms', 'O', 'Moz', 'Webkit'];

    if (s['transition'] == '') return true;
    while (v.length)
      if (v.pop() + 'Transition' in s)
        return true;
    return false;
  })();

  function scrollitems($strip, moveFirst) {
    var settings = $strip.data('settings') || {
      direction: "left"
    };
    if (typeof moveFirst === 'undefined')
      moveFirst = false;
    if (moveFirst) {
      moveFirstElement($strip);
    }
    var options = animationSettings($strip);
    $strip.animate(options.css, options.time, "linear", function() {
      $strip.css(settings.direction, '0');
      scrollitems($strip, true);
    });
  }

  function animationSettings($strip) {
    var settings = $strip.data('settings') || {
      direction: "left",
      speed: 50
    };
    var first = $strip.children().first();
    var distance = Math.abs(-$strip.css(settings.direction).replace('px', '').replace('auto', '0') - first.outerWidth(true));
    var settings = $strip.data('settings');
    var timeToComplete = distance * 1000 / settings.speed;
    var animationSettings = {};
    animationSettings[settings.direction] = $strip.css(settings.direction).replace('px', '').replace('auto', '0') - distance;
    return {
      'css': animationSettings,
      'time': timeToComplete
    };
  }

  function moveFirstElement($strip) {
    var settings = $strip.data('settings') || {
      direction: "left"
    };
    $strip.css('transition-duration', '0s').css(settings.direction, '0');
    var $first = $strip.children().first();
    if ($first.hasClass('webticker-init'))
      $first.remove();
    else
      $strip.children().last().after($first);
  }

  function css3Scroll($strip, moveFirst) {
    if (typeof moveFirst === 'undefined')
      moveFirst = false;
    if (moveFirst) {
      moveFirstElement($strip);
    }
    var options = animationSettings($strip);
    var time = options.time / 1000;
    time += 's';
    $strip.css(options.css).css('transition-duration', time);
  }

  function updaterss(rssurl, type, $strip) {
    var list = [];
    $.get(rssurl, function(data) {
      var $xml = $(data);
      $xml.find("item").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          item = {
            title: $this.find("title").text(),
            link: $this.find("link").text()
          }
        listItem = "<li><a href='" + item.link + "'>" + item.title + "</a></li>";
        list += listItem;
        //Do something with item here...
      });
      $strip.webTicker('update', list, type);
    });
  }

  function initalize($strip) {
    if ($strip.children('li').length < 1) {
      if (window.console) {
        console.log('no items to initialize');
      }
      return false;
    }

    var settings = $strip.data('settings');
    settings.duplicateLoops = settings.duplicateLoops || 0;

    $strip.width('auto');

    //Find the real width of all li elements
    var stripWidth = 0;
    $strip.children('li').each(function() {
      stripWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });

    if (stripWidth < $strip.parent().width() || $strip.children().length == 1) {
      //if duplicate items
      if (settings.duplicate) {
        //Check how many times to duplicate depending on width.
        itemWidth = Math.max.apply(Math, $strip.children().map(function() {
          return $(this).width();
        }).get());
        var duplicateLoops = 0;
        while (stripWidth - itemWidth < $strip.parent().width() || $strip.children().length == 1 || duplicateLoops < settings.duplicateLoops) {
          var listItems = $strip.children().clone();
          $strip.append(listItems);
          stripWidth = 0;
          $strip.children('li').each(function() {
            stripWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
          });
          itemWidth = Math.max.apply(Math, $strip.children().map(function() {
            return $(this).width();
          }).get());
          duplicateLoops++;
        }
        settings.duplicateLoops = duplicateLoops;
      } else {
        //if fill with empty padding
        var emptySpace = $strip.parent().width() - stripWidth;
        emptySpace += $strip.find("li:first").width();
        var height = $strip.find("li:first").height();

        $strip.append('<li class="ticker-spacer" style="width:' + emptySpace + 'px;height:' + height + 'px;"></li>');
      }
    }
    if (settings.startEmpty) {
      var height = $strip.find("li:first").height();
      $strip.prepend('<li class="webticker-init" style="width:' + $strip.parent().width() + 'px;height:' + height + 'px;"></li>');
    }
    //extra width to be able to move items without any jumps $strip.find("li:first").width()

    stripWidth = 0;
    $strip.children('li').each(function() {
      stripWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    $strip.width(stripWidth + 200);
    widthCompare = 0;
    $strip.children('li').each(function() {
      widthCompare += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    //loop to find weather the items inside the list are actually bigger then the size of the whole list. Increments in 200px.
    //only required when a single item is bigger then the whole list
    while (widthCompare >= $strip.width()) {
      $strip.width($strip.width() + 200);
      widthCompare = 0;
      $strip.children('li').each(function() {
        widthCompare += $(this).outerWidth(true);
      });
    }
    return true;
  }

  var methods = {
    init: function(settings) { // THIS
      settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed: 50, //pixels per second
        direction: "left",
        moving: true,
        startEmpty: true,
        duplicate: false,
        rssurl: false,
        hoverpause: true,
        rssfrequency: 0,
        updatetype: "reset"
      }, settings);
      //set data-ticker a unique ticker identifier if it does not exist
      return this.each(function() {
        jQuery(this).data('settings', settings);

        var $strip = jQuery(this);
        $strip.addClass("newsticker");
        var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
        $mask.after("<span class='tickeroverlay-left'>&nbsp;</span><span class='tickeroverlay-right'>&nbsp;</span>")
        var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");

        var started = initalize($strip);

        if (settings.rssurl) {
          updaterss(settings.rssurl, settings.type, $strip);
          if (settings.rssfrequency > 0) {
            window.setInterval(function() {
              updaterss(settings.rssurl, settings.type, $strip);
            }, settings.rssfrequency * 1000 * 60);
          }
        }

        if (cssTransitionsSupported) {
          //fix for firefox not animating default transitions
          $strip.css('transition-duration', '0s').css(settings.direction, '0');

          if (started) {
            //if list has items and set up start scrolling
            css3Scroll($strip, false);
          }
          //started or not still bind on the transition end event so it works after update
          $strip.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend', function(event) {
            if (!$strip.is(event.target)) {
              return false;
            }
            css3Scroll($(this), true);
          });
        } else {
          if (started) {
            //if list has items and set up start scrolling
            scrollitems($(this));
          }
        }

        if (settings.hoverpause) {
          $strip.hover(function() {
              if (cssTransitionsSupported) {
                var currentPosition = $(this).css(settings.direction);
                $(this).css('transition-duration', '0s').css(settings.direction, currentPosition);
              } else
                jQuery(this).stop();
            },
            function() {
              if (jQuery(this).data('settings').moving) {
                if (cssTransitionsSupported) {
                  css3Scroll($(this), false);
                  // $(this).css("-webkit-animation-play-state", "running");
                } else {
                  //usual continue stuff
                  scrollitems($strip);
                }
              }
            });
        }
      });
    },
    stop: function() {
      var settings = $(this).data('settings');
      if (settings.moving) {
        settings.moving = false;
        return this.each(function() {
          if (cssTransitionsSupported) {
            var currentPosition = $(this).css(settings.direction);
            $(this).css('transition-duration', '0s').css(settings.direction, currentPosition);
          } else
            $(this).stop();
        });
      }
    },
    cont: function() {
      var settings = $(this).data('settings')
      if (!settings.moving) {
        settings.moving = true;
        return this.each(function() {
          if (cssTransitionsSupported) {
            css3Scroll($(this), false);
          } else {
            scrollitems($(this));
          }
        });
      }
    },
    update: function(list, type, insert, remove) {
      type = type || "reset";
      if (typeof insert === 'undefined')
        insert = true;
      if (typeof remove === 'undefined')
        remove = false;
      if (typeof list === 'string') {
        list = $(list);
      }
      var $strip = $(this);
      $strip.webTicker('stop');
      var settings = $(this).data('settings');
      if (type == 'reset') {
        //this does a 'restart of the ticker'
        $strip.html(list);
        $strip.css(settings.direction, '0');
        initalize($strip);
      } else if (type == 'swap') {
        if (window.console) {
          console.log('trying to update');
        }
        if ($strip.children('li').length < 1) {
          //there were no items treat as if new
          $strip.html(list);
          $strip.css(settings.direction, '0');
          initalize($strip);
        } else {
          // should the update be a 'hot-swap' or use replacement for IDs (in which case remove new ones)
          $strip.children('li').addClass('old');
          for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            id = $(list[i]).data('update');
            match = $strip.find('[data-update="' + id + '"]'); //should try find the id or data-attribute.
            if (match.length < 1) {
              if (insert) {
                //we need to move this item into the dom
                if ($strip.find('.ticker-spacer:first-child').length == 0 && $strip.find('.ticker-spacer').length > 0) {
                  $strip.children('li.ticker-spacer').before(list[i]);
                } else {
                  $strip.append(list[i]);
                }
              }
            } else $strip.find('[data-update="' + id + '"]').replaceWith(list[i]);;
          };
          $strip.children('li.webticker-init, li.ticker-spacer').removeClass('old');
          if (remove)
            $strip.children('li').remove('.old');
          stripWidth = 0;
          $strip.children('li').each(function() {
            stripWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
          });
          $strip.width(stripWidth + 200);
        }
      }

      $strip.webTicker('cont');
    }
  };

  $.fn.webTicker = function(method) {

    // Method calling logic
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.webTicker');
    }

  };

})(jQuery);

/* Initializing the webticker */

$("#webticker").webTicker({
  speed: 60,
  direction: "left",
  moving: true,
  startEmpty: true,
  duplicate: false,
  rssurl: false,
  rssfrequency: 0,
  updatetype: "reset",
  hoverpause: true
});

/* Executing the function on button click to toggle the webticker */

$('button').on('click', function() {

  $("#webticker").toggle();

});
```

```css
/* liScroll styles */

.tickeroverlay-left {} .tickeroverlay-right {} .tickercontainer {
  /* the outer div */
  /*background: #000000;*/
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tickercontainer .mask {
  /* that serves as a mask. so you get a sort of padding both left and right */
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.newsticker {
  /* that's your list */
  /*Transitions have been added in order set css3 transitions; and have linear easing. Changing these lines you might have unexpected results */
  -webkit-transition: all 0s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0s linear;
  transition: all 0s linear;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font: bold 10px Verdana;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Digital dream';
}
ul.newsticker li {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: gray;
  float: left;
  /* important: display inline gives incorrect results when you check for elem's width */
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.newsticker a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  color: gray;
  font: bold 10px Verdana;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
ul.newsticker span {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.ticker-toggle {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="webticker">
  <li id='item1'>My First News Item</li>
  <li id='item2'>My Second News Item</li>
  <li id='item3'>My Third News Item</li>
  <li id='item4'>My Fourth News Item</li>
  <li id='item5'>My Fifth News Item</li>
  <li id='item6'>My Sixth News Item</li>
  <li id='item7'>My Seventh News Item</li>
  <li id='item8'>My Eighth News Item</li>
  <li id='item9'>My Ninth News Item</li>
  <li id='item10'>My Tenth News Item</li>
</ul>

<div class="ticker-toggle">
  <button type="button">Ticker Toggle</button>
</div>
```